# restore MacBook from sparse image

Tags: backup, hard-drive, ssd, restore

I recently wiped my MBP hard drive as well as installing a new SSD.

I have a sparseimage backup of my old drive (created with Carbon Copy Cloner) that I want to restore onto the SSD.

I've tried to restore using disk utility but I seem to be getting inconsistent error messages.

The instructions on the CCC website don't seem to work for my restore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: "resource temoporarily unavailable" trying to scan, Could not restore - Device not configured,  Restore Failure - could not get resource volume name are a few of what I've had

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want to use CCC to restore the image as well? The single time I did this, I just swapped source-destination and it worked a treat. CCC should be better able to handle it's own data…

Comment: how though when there's nothing on the drive to begin with? Thought of reinstalling the OS and then restore over the top but that won't revert system files because they'd be in use for the actual restore? The general info out there seems to be pretty vague considering I won't have been the first person to want to do this.

Comment: re System files you want the ones from the latest version so does not matter if they don't get copied over - anyway CCC will work

Comment: I understand that you have a sparse-image backup - You don't have a bootable image somewhere? Ideally you need a USB key or hard disk to boot from, with the CCC, then you can run the sparse-image over to the new disk. If there's sufficient room on the disk with the sparse image, why not install the OS to that disk?

I'm sure you know what you need to boot OSX to install - it may be you have to reinstall, then create a USB stick with OSX & CCC installed, then reinstall using CCC from the sparse-image. Yep - gonna take lots of time.